# Problemas con checkbox Angular 6

Tags: angular, yii

Tengo un problema al editar una propiedad en mi web el cual esta propiedad posee un listado de ambientes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**En dicho listado cuando se crea se guardan bien**. El problema pasa cuando se edita algunos campos seleccionados no se guardan y los que ya estaba se eliminan.
En el request se envian los que estaba seleccionados como un boolean (true) como lo voy a mostrar en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo html

```
<div class="checkbox col-md-6 col-12" *ngFor="let e of ambientes">
              <label class="w-100">
                <div class="row col-12">
                  <div class="col">
                    <input type="checkbox" [value]="e.id" name="ambientes{{e.id}}" [(ngModel)]="model.ambientes[e.id]">&nbsp;{{e.nombre}}</div>
                </div>
              </label>
            </div>
```

De backend uso Yii 2 dejo el codigo

```
if (!$nueva){ //si no es nueva se borran los registros actuales
        Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->delete('propiedad_has_ambiente',['id_propiedad'=>$prop->id])->execute();
      }
      foreach ($data['ambientes'] as $k => $v){
        if($v){
          $e = new PropiedadHasAmbiente();
          $e->id_propiedad = $prop->id;
          $e->id_ambiente  = $k;
          $e->save(false);
        }
      }
```